# Java. Метод продолжает работу после return? Аномалия или непонимание?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, у меня есть метод который ищет элемент в бинарном дереве и проблема в том что он ведет себя невероятно странно. Когда я прошел по нему дебагером оказалось что все работает в точности как я задумал но после прохождения строки `return` метод не заканчивает работу, а начинает выполнять еще какие-то непонятные действия. Это просто ломает все мое понимание того как работают методы.

вот код:

```
@Override
public Leaf<E> find(E elem) {
    Leaf<E> eLeaf = new Leaf<>(elem);
    return binarySearch(root, eLeaf);
}

private Leaf<E> binarySearch(Leaf<E> leaf, Leaf<E> eLeaf) {
    int compare = leaf.compareTo(eLeaf);

    if (compare < 0 && leaf.right != null) {
        binarySearch(leaf.right, eLeaf);
    }

    if (compare > 0 && leaf.left != null) {
        binarySearch(leaf.left, eLeaf);
    }

    if (compare == 0) {
        return leaf;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Если быть точным все идет нормально но потом он находит совпадение в месте:

```
if (compare == 0) {
    return leaf;
}
```

Заходит на строку `return leaf;` вроде-бы все... Синяя полоска дебагера зашла на `return`, дебагер печатает мне адрес объекта который сейчас вернется... Но нет, вдруг он возвращается в второй `if`! Как такое возможно? Разве запись `return` не гарантирует что работа метода будет завершена?

Comment: это не бинарный поиск - это поиск в глубину.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да это я не удачно назвал.

Comment: Более внимательно смотрите, что происходит со стеком вызовов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас рекурсия. Идет возвращение на предыдущий уровень. Перед этим выполнялся первый вызов метода в `if`. После `return` идет переход ко второму `if`.

Возможно, задумывалось как-то так:

```
private Leaf<E> binarySearch(Leaf<E> leaf, Leaf<E> eLeaf) {
    int compare = leaf.compareTo(eLeaf);

    if (compare < 0 && leaf.right != null) {
        return binarySearch(leaf.right, eLeaf);
    }

    if (compare > 0 && leaf.left != null) {
        return binarySearch(leaf.left, eLeaf);
    }

    if (compare == 0) {
        return leaf;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: а пардон в чем разница? это же копия кода который я писал

Comment: все доперло спасибо большое